# Form Submit works with Button, but not with Enter key

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am new here, so maybe you need to give me some hints about how everything works in this community. I was already reading a lot here on Stackoverflow but finally signed up.

I am designing a small website for a museum near me which is a non-profit organization. They have a huge collection of ammunition and the information is currently available on paper.

I want a website where I can enter a number and the appropiate information is shown. Everything works so far in my test site. (since no internet available there, it should run locally on a android tablet later)

The only problem I have is that the form submit works with the button, but not with the enter key or "open" key on the androids numberpad.

I am also quite new to javascript-coding since I come from electronics and c-programming on microprocessors, so I may have made mistake.

i currently have the iframe in the main page, but i originally wanted it to open up in a modal. It did not work properly, so maybe I may try that later again.

Live demo here: [museum.smallfilms.ch/drei](http://museum.smallfilms.ch/drei)

The code for the form is the following:

```
 <!-- Jumbotron Header -->
    <header class="jumbotron hero-spacer">
        <h1>Katalog:</h1>
        <p>Mit der Munitionsnummer können hier weitere Informationen zur jeweiligen Patrone angezeigt werden.</p>
        <p>
<form onsubmit="searchpage()">
    <input type="number" pattern="\d*"/min="1" max="9999" id="num" >
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="searchpage()" id="search">Suchen</button>
</form>
```

The Javascript code is the following:

```
function searchpage() {


  var num = document.getElementById('num');
  var targetFrame = document.getElementById('targetFrame');


  if (num.value) {
    var page = 'pages/' + (+num.value) + '.html';
    targetFrame.setAttribute('src', page);
  }
}
```

If you need more code I can deliver this. Just let me know that you need.

The site is now designed to show something for the numbers 1 and 2.

The whole site uses bootstrap and the sites displayed in the iframe use strapdown.js for easier editing. (We need to digitalize about 900 datasets in the end)

I think it is only a small mistake somewhere but after hours of coding and searching the internet i still did not get the source of the error.

Thanks in advance for any help and hint.

Dabbax

Edit: if it helps, i packed the whole page into a zip... [museum.smallfilms.ch/drei/drei.zip](http://museum.smallfilms.ch/drei/drei.zip)

Comment: change your button type to `type='submit'`

Comment: @NicholasSmith That unfortunately does not solve the problem...

Answer (score 1):

I think that the error comes from the line where you are calling the function searchPage(). I would recommend you to try the line below :

```
<input type="sumbit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="searchpage()" id="search" value="Suchen">
```

In this case, when you press enter, the form will be submitted and call the searchPage function.

Answer (score 1):

On your code for the form, try:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="searchpage()" id="search"> Suchen </button>
```

edit: Shaam's answer can be correct but if you say `input` then you just trying to make it a look like `button` with bootstrap, a more proper approach would be `input type="button"` but in your case you should say that this is a `button` that submit the form.

That's why you should use `button` and not `input` here.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I already tried that and some strange things happen.


- Firefox Mac OS X: no change
- Chrome on Android: not even the button works anymore
- Standard Browser on Android: Button and Numberpad-Open-Button works
- Safari Max OS X: nothing works anymore

Comment: Not sure if i can help you more based on the code you provided. I tried that on your page via Inspect Element and seems to work pretty good. Was that the only thing you canged on your code? From type="button" to type=:"submit"

Comment: do you need additional code? I could upload the whole website folder as a zip? I am new to this and maybe I made some newbie-mistakes :S

Comment: I just saw that you are calling twice the `searchpage()` both on button and form. Remove the `onclick` from button and try again please.

Comment: Still works on mobile android browser, but not on mobile chrome and OSX Firefox and Safari. The site seems to load the iframe but still the same content as before. So, may it be that the js-function does not properly set the src of the iframe?

Comment: i could say "meh it works on mobile android, task done" but for learning purposes I really would like to understand why it is behaving that way

Comment: if it helps, i packed the whole page into a zip... museum.smallfilms.ch/drei/drei.zip

Comment: Your code is a bit of too messy. You should really try to code through an IDE like NetBeans or what you prefer, see the suggestions and errors and fix them one by one. You can understand i can't go through all that code. The problem seems to be a combination of other things too. Try coding one by one see what works and where it works and then you can find the problem and ask the proper questions every time. For that question the answers you were looking are those you have get. Please if my (or another) answer is correct accept it by ticking the correct button below the up and down vote.

Comment: Thanks, i'll give netbeans a try.

Answer (score 0):

This could be your html:

```
<form id="searchForm" action="some_url">
    <input type="number" pattern="\d*"/min="1" max="9999" id="num" >
    <input type="button"  value="Suchen" class="btn btn-danger entr" onclick="searchpage()" id="search">
</form>
```

Now add an event listener to the class `entr` and submit the form if the key is <kbd>Enter</kbd>. So the event listener in jquery like

```
$('.entr').keypress(function(event) {
      if (event.which == 13) { // this is the enter key code
            document.getElementById('searchForm').submit();
      }
});
```